# User registration on subsite in multisite configuration

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management

As a network admin in multisite configuration, I have the option to enable or disable the user registration \ site registration. is there any way i can enable the user registration on s single sub site , not on all sites.

In my WP setup, I have a main blog which is managed by me and I dont want user to register here. i have a another blog installed on sub directory dedicated for forum. I would like to enable user registration here, so that user can use the forum

Comment: Did you try the settings at the individual site level? That should work independently

Comment: There is no option to set user registration in individual sites

Comment: oh yes you are right... My bad :)

Comment: As you have found WordPress on its own doesn't allow sub-site registration and many of the plugins expect the user to belong to the main site at least before granting other sub-sites. There is a new plugin [network-subsite-user-registration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/network-subsite-user-registration/) which does want you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multisite setup allows you to enable and disable user registration at the network level but if you see the database it store the value in the **`wp_options`** tables for each site.

So we can try the below and see if this work.

Use the below code in the **`functions.php`** file.

```
function wpse_enable_user_registration( $blog_id = 1 ) {
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    // Fetching the present option
    $user_registration_option = get_option( 'users_can_register', 0 );

    if( '0' == $user_registration_option )
        $site_registration_option = update_option( 'users_can_register', 1 );

    restore_current_blog(); // Switches back to the original blog

    return $site_registration_option;
}
```

If the updation is successful, you will get `true` else `false`

Now you can use the function to enable any subsites in the MU setup by passing the sub sites `id` to the function in place of `$blog_id`

Comment: Does this need to hook into anything?

Comment: Depends on your requirement. You can hook it or else you can use it as a function passing the blog id

Comment: Seems to me this does the same thing as changing the "Users can register" value in the Network Admin -> Edit Site -> Settings Tab. That does not appear to have any effect if the global registration setting is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Multisite adds a filter for `get_option('users_can_register')` calls in `ms-functions.php` `users_can_register_signup_filter`. This filter circumvents any blog-level settings you try to implement.

```
/**
 * Check whether users can self-register, based on Network settings.
 *
 * @since MU
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function users_can_register_signup_filter() {
    $registration = get_site_option('registration');
    if ( $registration == 'all' || $registration == 'user' )
        return true;

    return false;
}
add_filter('option_users_can_register', 'users_can_register_signup_filter');
```