# why in my wordpress admin panel the membership option is not showing

Tags: plugins, admin

In my wordpress admin panel general settings membership check box is not showing please check the screenshot and kindly help me to resolve it Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting is not visible on individual sites in a Multisite Network. Instead this setting is set at a Network level on the [Network Admin Settings Screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Settings_Screen).

If you need to control this setting per-site, see [this previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124532/user-registration-on-subsite-in-multisite-configuration) on the topic.